# How to create a deb package when upstream developer has not a release a tarball

Tags: 12.04, package-management, packaging

I want to create a deb package of https://github.com/manojgudi/sandhi. But I cannot find any tarball there. All the tutorials that I came across on the net assume that there is an upstream tarball available. I am new to this. Please guide me in the right direction!

@ bodhi.zazen By download the source do you mean I do this -

```
git clone http://github.com/manojgudi/sandhi.git
cd sandhi/
git submodule init
git submodule update
git pull origin master
git submodule update
```

and then right click on folder "sandhi" and compress it to create a tarball? or should I do these first:

```
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
make -j 2
```

and then make a tarball?

Comment: Check out https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingWithGit

Comment: download the source and make a tar ball ;)

Comment: Or there's an option to download a zip file. Unzip and make a tarball.

Comment: The source tar ball used to make a .deb must, by definition, contain only what is provided by upstream, unaltered in any way, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/first.en.html#workflow , in your case you just need to package the files into a tarball, do not alter them.

Answer (score 0):

- Actually, Github provides a way to export zip source archive, check right side of repository home:

  https://github.com/manojgudi/sandhi/archive/master.zip
- Another way is to make it yourself from git clone, using CMake & Make:

  ```
  mkdir build
  cd build
  cmake ..
  make dist
  ```

**Reference:** [CMake and “make dist”](https://agateau.wordpress.com/2009/08/09/cmake-and-make-dist/)